# How should browser and version be one hot encoded?

Tags: machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

I need to output browser and version data for one hot encoding. We have come up with a few options (outlined below). I did some searching but couldn't find any existing examples of someone with similar data (searched [Kaggle Datasets](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets?sortBy=relevance&group=public&search=browser&page=1&pageSize=20&size=all&filetype=all&license=all) and [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=one+%22hot%22+encoding+browser+name+version)).

- Option 1: One column with browser name and version joined together

  - e.g. "browser_version" column values: "Safari-1.2.3", "Chrome-4.5.6", "Firefox-7.8.9"

```
| order_id | browser_version |
| 1        | Safari-1.2.3    |
| 2        | Chrome-4.5.6    |
| 3        | Firefox-7.8.9   |
```

- Option 2: Two columns: one with browser name, another with browser version

  - e.g. "browser" (column 1) values: "Safari", "Chrome", "Firefox"
  - e.g. "version" (column 2) values: "1.2.3", "4.5.6", "7.8.9"

```
| order_id | browser | version |
| 1        | Safari  | 1.2.3   |
| 2        | Chrome  | 4.5.6   |
| 3        | Firefox | 7.8.9   |
```

- Option 3: Two columns: one with browser name, another with browser name and version joined together

  - e.g. "browser" (column 1) values: "Safari", "Chrome", "Firefox"
  - e.g. "browser_version" (column 2) values: "Safari-1.2.3", "Chrome-4.5.6", "Firefox-7.8.9"

```
| order_id | browser | browser_version |
| 1        | Safari  | Safari-1.2.3    |
| 2        | Chrome  | Chrome-4.5.6    |
| 3        | Firefox | Firefox-7.8.9   |
```

What is the most beneficial way to set up the data values (assuming a CSV file, columns) for one hot encoding?

I suppose the correct answer might be to test each option and check the results but I thought this is likely is something that has been done before so I figured it's worth an ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the first option. It will give on index per pair (browser | version).

The second option put version number of different browsers in the same column, whereas these numbers are not comparable. You can compare a Chrome version number with another Chrome version number but not a Chrome version number with a Firefox one.

And the third option contains the first one, with additional redundant data.

Comment: Appreciate the input, thanks. I'll test and try to remember to report back :)